# compare two array and add 0 to missing element

Tags: javascript

I am stuck with a nested array. I need to plot a graph using a highchart.

I am able to transform data as required by the graph. However, I need to check the company name exists in this transformed array list with another array list which consists of a static element like ['BCM', 'CGRLH', 'HMS', 'Insurance']. As you can see sometimes the vertical array in each object consist of one or two-element.

example: first obj Attrition got 3 elements in the vertical array and 3 elements in the data property. I want to add 0 to all the data property in result array. like [1, 2, 0, 4] because 'HMS' is missing. Please let me know how can I achieve it.

**API Response:**

```
const categoriesWise = [
  {
    vertical: 'BCM',
    total: '297',
    values: [
      {
        keyword: 'Attrition',
        countOfKeyword: 24
      },
      {
        keyword: 'Backlog',
        countOfKeyword: 6
      },
      {
        keyword: 'Complaince',
        countOfKeyword: 12
      }
    ]
  }, 
  {
   vertical: 'CGRLH',
    total: '300',
    values: [
      {
        keyword: 'Attrition',
        countOfKeyword: 20
      },
      {
        keyword: 'Backlog',
        countOfKeyword: 10
      },
      {
        keyword: 'Complaince',
        countOfKeyword: 14
      }
    ]
  },
  {
   vertical: 'HMS',
    total: '250',
    values: [
      {
        keyword: 'Backlog',
        countOfKeyword: 16
      },
      {
        keyword: 'Complaince',
        countOfKeyword: 11
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**API Data transformation Code in VueJS**

```
formatCategoryWiseChartData(categoriesWise) {
      const data = [];
      const result = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < categoriesWise.length; i += 1) {
        const total = categoriesWise[i].total;
        categoriesWise[i].values.forEach((e) => {
          data.push({ name: e.keyword, data: [(e.countofkeyword * 100) / total], vertical: [categoriesWise[i].verticalName] });
        });
      }
      data.forEach((item) => {
        const existing = result.filter((resultItem) => resultItem.name === item.name);
        if (existing.length) {
          const existingIndex = result.indexOf(existing[0]);
          result[existingIndex].data.push(...item.data);
          result[existingIndex].vertical.push(...item.vertical);
        } else {
          result.push(item);
        }
      });
      console.log('result reached --->', result);
      return result;
    },
```

**Transformed array below**

Result: (Example not actual values)

```
const result = [
  {
    name: 'Attrition',
    data: [1, 2, 3],
    vertical: ['BCM', 'CGRLH', 'Insurance']
  },
  {
    name: 'Backlog',
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4],
    vertical: ['BCM', 'CGRLH', 'HMS', 'Insurance']
  },
  {
    name: 'Complaince',
    data: [1],
    vertical: ['Insurance']
  }
]
```

Comment: Before data would help too

Comment: You should correct the output or the description to fit one another, even after reading your question 3 times, I don't understand it or there are multiple errors in it

Comment: please check now

Comment: @MeetSingh The code above doesn't produce the result you put. How can we help you fix the algorithm that we don't know it and we know the other irrelevant instead?

Comment: If the question was just simply `compare two array and add 0 to missing element`, then there must be `if (something) push.element` in your code. Try adding `else push(0)`.

`if (something) push.(number) else push(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an array of the static elements and assign the values to the same index.

```js
var categoriesWise = [{ vertical: 'BCM', total: '297', values: [{ keyword: 'Attrition', countOfKeyword: 24 }, { keyword: 'Backlog', countOfKeyword: 6 }, { keyword: 'Complaince', countOfKeyword: 12 }] }, { vertical: 'CGRLH', total: '300', values: [{ keyword: 'Attrition', countOfKeyword: 20 }, { keyword: 'Backlog', countOfKeyword: 10 }, { keyword: 'Complaince', countOfKeyword: 14 }] }, { vertical: 'HMS', total: '250', values: [{ keyword: 'Backlog', countOfKeyword: 16 }, { keyword: 'Complaince', countOfKeyword: 11 }] }],
    staticValues = ['BCM', 'CGRLH', 'HMS', 'Insurance'],
    result = categoriesWise.reduce((r, { vertical, total, values }) => {
        values.forEach(({ keyword: name, countOfKeyword }) => {
            var temp = r.find(q => q.name === name);
            if (!temp) r.push(temp = { name, data: staticValues.map(_ => 0), vertical: [...staticValues] });
            temp.data[staticValues.indexOf(vertical)] = countOfKeyword * 100 / total;
        });
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```